# dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting: unknown system group

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, debian

I have tried to install `inkscape`, with

```
$sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

But I got an error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown system group 'smmsp' in statoverride file; the system group got removed
before the override, which is most probably a packaging bug, to recover you
can remove the override manually with dpkg-statoverride
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

should i remove that group `smmsp` causing the error? What does even mean `system group` here? and what is in `statoverride` file, what configuration?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

Open a terminal and run:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Comment: It works. However it would be nice to have some explanations.